# Regex dashes inside character class

Tags: regex, perl

Here is the UTF-8 encoded input file `in`:

```
-
–
—
a.-b
a.–b
a.—b

a.”b
```

When I do find and replace En dash or Em dash **inside a character class**, I get corrupt output file with some encoding problems

```
perl -p0e 's@\.[–]+@\. @g' in > out_err
```

While with the same command, but with **dashes as literals**, I get no problems:

```
perl -p0e 's@\.–+@\. @g' in > out_ok
```

Same situation is with Python

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x94 in position 10: invalid start byte

The question is why?

Comment: It is a UTF8 file right? Use `perl -CSD -Mutf8 -p0e 's@\.–+@. @g' in > out_err`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this is not exactly the duplicate.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One needs to add `-CSDA -Mutf8` options for this to work:

```
perl -CSDA -Mutf8 -p0e 's@\.[-–—]+@. @g' in > OUT
```

Explanation of *why* and of these command line options here:

https://perldoc.perl.org/perl581delta.html#UTF-8-no-longer-default-under-UTF-8-locales

[https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-C-%5b_number%2flist_%5d*](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-C-%5B_number%2list_%5D*)

Comment: @Wiktor what's the problem with my question / my answer? why downvoting the question, marking it as duplicate, downvoting the answer and voting for its deletion, all without any explanations - if it's a proper question and I gave it a proper answer ?

Answer (score 0):

I think "why" may be the shell. The same regexp works for me, in a file:

```
use utf8;
use strict;
open HIN, '<:utf8', 'in';
open HOUT, '>:utf8', 'out_ok';
while (<HIN>) {
   $_ =~ s@\.[–]+@\. @g;
   print HOUT $_;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work for me for the perl command above

Comment: Yes, I know, that's the point: you asked "why"; I think there is nothing wrong in your regexp, it doesn't work from the command line because of some behaviour of the shell you are using. Non knowing what shell is it (bash of Linux, cmd of Windows) it's difficult to suggest a line command that does work.

Comment: As for perl, though, the suggestion of Wiktor Stribiżew seems promising: as you are putting utf8 characters in the source (be it a file or a line command), the utf8 module has to be used.

Comment: I am using GNU bash, version 5.0.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) but the problem is not with it - cause I don't have it for literals, - but with perl - and Wiktor Stribiżew's suggestion worked quite well here.. Will add an answer